# Iterate through input fields where the name is only partially static

Tags: jquery, dom

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application and I use strongly typed razor view. That's why the input fields look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="True" name="[13].IsRequired" data-val-required="The IsRequired field is required." data-val="true">
```

I want to iterate those fields where `value="True"`. The identifier is the name but the name is constructed with the index (in this case `[13].` + `IsRequired` which is the same for all fields. So basically I need to ignore the index and look only for `IsRequired`.

Comment: Have a look at the list of attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name$="IsRequired"]')
```

should do it

Comment: Do you know how I can take the type of the input. I tried this : `    $('input[name$="IsRequired"]').each(function () {
            alert($(this).type);
    })` but it returns `undefined` always?

Comment: try `alert($(this).attr('type'));`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('input[value="True"][name$="IsRequired"]')
```